# @And annotation in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I am going through some examples and some books in relation to Cucumber usage and it looks like `@And` annotation is never being caught by the regex. I mean it is a valid Gherkin keyword and **it is** being used in the scenarios but I can see no references to it in the actual code.

Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From The Cucumber Book:

Cucumber doesn’t actually care which of these keywords you use; the choice
is simply there to help you create the most readable scenario.

Some people find Given, When, Then, And, and But a little verbose. There is an
additional keyword you can use to start a step: * (an asterisk).

So you could write:

Scenario: Attempt withdrawal using stolen card
                                     **Given** I have $100 in my account
**But** my card is invalid
**When** I request $50
**Then** my card should not be returned
**And** I should be told to contact the bank

Or:

Scenario: Attempt withdrawal using stolen card
                                     **Given** I have $100 in my account
**Given** my card is invalid
**When** I request $50
**Then** my card should not be returned
**Then** I should be told to contact the bank

Or:

Scenario: Attempt withdrawal using stolen card
                                     * I have $100 in my account
* my card is invalid
* I request $50
* my card should not be returned
* I should be told to contact the bank

To Cucumber, this is exactly the same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because @AND keyword is parsed like the keyword prior to it. So, in case your test looks like that

```
@When user logs in application
@And navigates to landing page
```

it's similar to the the case below

```
@When user logs in application
@When navigates to landing page
```

Actually, I stick to avoid using @AND keywords, because binding mismatch could occur if someone will insert a step which begins from different keyword. E.g.:

```
@When user logs in application
**@Then check that userpic is displayed**
@And navigates to landing page
```

In this example @AND keyword will be remapped to keyword @THEN.

Comment: But, as the [accepted answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/31248/31044) says, the keywords are irrelevant, so there is no "binding mismatch" even if somebody inserts a step with a different keyword above `And`.